# How it is spread? or How does it spread?

Tags: meaning

If I want to ask about the mechanism of transfer of disease flu or AIDS

How can I say conversation?

How does it spread?
or how it is spread?

How flu spread?
How flu is spread?
How flu does spread?

Comment: "How does it spread?" and "How is it spread?" are both legitimate ways of asking about the transmission of a communicable disease.  "How it is spread?" is not correct English, however.

Comment: 'Spread' is an irregular verb, spelled the same for present, past, and past(passive) participle.   Viruses are spread (passively) between individuals by the hosts conduct, and spread themselves (actively) between cells (and figuratively through the population because we can't see them).

Answer (score -1):

to **transmit**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transmit)

> 2. To cause to spread; pass on: transmit an infection.

As in:

> How is disease X **transmitted**?